# Speed of news ticker

Tags: css, html

I have HTML news ticker and I want to minimize the speed of the ticker.

This is my code:

```
  <marquee behavior="scroll" Height=20 direction="right" 
        onmouseover="this.stop();" 
        onmouseout="this.start();">
         رام الله
    </marquee>
    <iframe src="http://geo.molg.pna.ps/l3.html" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:94%;width:100%" height="94%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Leave in latest world. marquee is older. Use css3

Comment: @Majdoleen I think what *ketan* is trying to say (in a strikingly poetic way) is that [`<marquee>` is dead and gone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee). Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link to control the speed of marquee tag.
http://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/html_marquee_speed.php

```
<marquee style="font-family:Book Antiqua; color: #FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000080" scrolldelay="500">This is an example of Marquee (Delay : 500 Milliseconds)</marquee>
```

Instead of marquee tag, you can use any jquery plugins like [jquerynewsticker](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
scrollamount="5"
```

scrollamount controls the speed of text: higher the value higher is the scrolling speed

Answer (score 0):

add attribute scrolldelay to marquee tag

```
<marquee scrolldelay="200"></marquee>
```